# While loop with inner assignments causing checkstyle errors

Tags: java, while-loop, variable-assignment

I'm going through my code to make sure it conforms to CheckStyle standards.

I personally feel that the rule "No Inner Assignments" makes the code more complicated to understand (you have to look in 3 places instead of 1).

Is there some way that I could preserve my single area by creating a {} block within the while loop to perform my assignments and return a boolean?!

What are your opinions?

```
File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

// Inner Assignment
while ((int i = fileInputStream.readLine()) != -1)
{
  //
}

// No Inner Assignment
int i = fileInputStream.readLine();
while(i!= -1)
{
  //
  i = in.readLine();
}
```

I encounter similar issues when I require a while loop which assigns a combination of some variable using, for example the ++ operator.

Would this for loop be considered a better alternative (it does comply with checkstyle)

```
for (int i = fileInputStream.readLine(); i != -1; i = fileInputStream.readLine())
{
  //
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? You can choose to not use checkstyle; you could disable the inner assignment check; or you could remove your inner assignments. If you want to control the scope of your variable(s) your certainly could create a block to define them and limit their scope, but why exactly?

Comment: is it possible to do a block while({})?

Comment: Yes. See the solution below. You could also use an anonymous block. That is `{ a = scanner.nextInt(); if (a != -1) System.out.print(a); }`

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite your loop as an infinite loop with a `break` in the middle, like this:

```
while(true) {
    int i = fileInputStream.readLine();
    if (i == -1) break;
}
```

Note that `i` can be moved inside the loop: the only value that it can have upon exiting the loop is `-1`, so there is no reason to keep the variable visible outside the loop.

Comment: nice suggestion. led me to construct this for loop:
for (int i = fileInputStream.readLine(); i != -1; i = fileInputStream.readLine())
{
 //
}

Comment: @DannyRancher The `for` loop repeats the `fileInputStream.readLine()` part. I thought your goal was to avoid this repetition, no?

Comment: Actually my goal is to not split the code in several places (which your solution achieved).

Comment: Isn't an infinite loop worse from a clean code perspective?

Comment: @keiki Why? It's a clean construct, and it's reasonably common in imperative languages. In fact, in some languages (e.g. Ada) there is a separate language construct for making infinite loops.